# Installing Azure Powershell cmdlets, cancelled, end task during install

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, web-platform-installer

I think I blew up my Web Platform Installer. I was trying to add Azure Powershell cmdlets but had some internet connectivity issues while the download was happening so I decided to cancel the install. The cancel appeared to stall so I pulled up task manager and hit 'end task' on the Web Platform Installer. Now I am unable to install the Powershell cmdlets because "Another installation is already in progress. Complete that installation before proceeding with this installation".

How do you fix this without doing a clean Windows install?

Edit: apparently this error is only happening for the Azure Powershell cmdlets. I was successfully able to install the xplat-cli (even though I don't need it). Just wanted to see if the WPI was completely borked or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Task Manager on the local computer (right-click the system tray and select 'Start task Manager')
2. Under the processes tab, select any processes named 'msiexec.exe' (there could be multiple entries) and then press 'End Process'.
3. Perform the installation once more.